# Delete the last schema and keep Subject in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I have a subject with only 1 schema, then I want to delete this schema, but unfortunately, the subject is triggered to delete. I want to keep the subject to post a new schema. Any solution to keep it? Or the way to create the subject again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to create the subject again. A subject cannot exist with no versions